# attr_accessor which transforms nil into string on write

Tags: ruby

I have a data object that contains dozens of attr_accessor fields for various inputs. Can I somehow define the class so that all setters for all fields will e.g. set the value as an empty string instead of the attempted nil?

Comment: What do you mean "the attempted nil"?

Comment: If someone attempts to object.foo = nil, it would actually result the variable foo to be set "" instead of nil.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a little module to do it:

```
module NilToBlankAttrAccessor

  def nil_to_blank_attr_accessor(attr)
    attr_reader attr
    define_method "#{attr}=" do |value|
      value = '' if value.nil?
      instance_variable_set "@#{attr}", value
    end
  end

end
```

Just mix it in:

```
class Foo
  extend NilToBlankAttrAccessor
  nil_to_blank_attr_accessor :bar
end
```

And use it:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bar = nil
p foo.bar        # => ""
foo.bar = 'abc'
p foo.bar        # => "abc"
```

**How it works**

`NilToBlankAttrAccessor#nil_to_blank_attr_accessor` first defines the attr_reader normally:

```
    attr_reader attr
```

Then it defines the writer by defining a method with the same name as the accessor, only with an "=" at the end.  So, for attribute `:bar`, the method is named `bar=`

```
    define_method "#{attr}=" do |value|
      ...
    end
```

Now it needs to set the variable.  First it turns nil into an empty string:

```
      value = '' if value.nil?
```

Then use instance_variable_set, which does an instance variable assignment where the instance variable isn't known until runtime.

```
      instance_variable_set "@#{attr}", value
```

Class Foo needs nil_to_blank_attr_accessor to be a class method, not an instance method, so it uses `extend` instead of `include`:

```
class Foo
  extend NilToBlankAttrAccessor
  ...
end
```

Comment: That will change not only `nil` but also `false` into `""`.

Comment: @WayneConrad That's a nice answer and great explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
object.foo = given_input
```

you should do

```
object.foo = given_input.nil? ? "" : given_input
```

or if you want to turn `false` into `""` as well, then

```
object.foo = given_input || ""
```